# Mean Value Theorem help

Tags: multivariable-calculus

once again.

I wish to prove that
$$\frac{2}{\pi} = \cos\left( \frac{\pi t}{2}\right) + \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{2} ( 1-t ) \right)$$

for some t in the interval $( 0, 1 )$ given the function

$$f( x, y ) = \sin(\pi x ) + \cos(\pi y ).$$

I was told that I could prove it using the mean value theorem, but I am not exactly sure how to use it in this case.

Thank you for your help ahead of time.

Comment: It should be $\sin$ instead of $\cos$. I have edited it. Thank you for mentioning it.

Comment: That changes the context of my original comment, so I deleted that. As now written, this indicates that $ \ x \ =  \frac{1-t}{2} \ , \ y \ = \ \frac{t}{2} \ . $

Comment: I'm not sure about using the _Mean_ Value Theorem.  The _Intermediate_ Value Theorem can help: the function is continuous and we are considering a parameterized path from $ \ (\frac{1}{2},0) \ $ to $ \ (0, \frac{1}{2}) \ . $  What are the values of the function at the endpoints?  Where is $  \ \frac{2}{\pi} \ $ in relation to those function values?